# Execute a .sh file from the desktop in intervalls

Tags: shell, script, desktop

We've got a bad hoster, that only allows cronjob in 15 min. intervals. However sometimes we get time critical stuff and we need to do it in faster intervals.

That said, the hoster allows an execution via ssh command line in far lower time intervals, like every minute.

So I'm looking for a desktop solution that'll execute the .sh script in intervals I set up and run in the background until the task is complete.

That means I first have to log in with my account data and password, then navigate where the .sh script lies, and then execute it in set intervals.

How do I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you need an every-minute cronjob on your local system that logs in to your remote box and just executes the program. Don't try to reimplement cron.

Comment: Also, set up ssh public keys so you don't need to hardcode your password anywhere

Comment: And how do I do that?

Comment: lots of tutorials out there. google it